# Newbie: Where to move generated html files in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have an azure site which is run from a VM. It has nodejs and mongodb on it.

One of the functions of the site is to generate html files which are then passed to other users via their URL. I expect a high volume of requests for the URLs and hence I do not want them to be hosted on my VM (I am on a very low tier plan at the moment).

What options does Azure provide? A friend who is in the AWS camp mentioned S3 but as I am already using Azure how would I do it here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean byt "passed to others" but if you are talking about downloading things then (based off S3) Azure has what is called [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) which is designed as an off VM storage area to host static files for serving. The website I run that is hosted off Azure stores all my static files for download from here. It is cheep storage and won't eat up your Azure VM space.

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments by David Makogon you should actually be able to server the HTML files up from blob storage AFTER they have been generated and stored there, so your VM generates the HTML and saves it to BLOB and BLOB serves it up.

Comment: Hi Matthew. Html files will be generated so they are not 'static files' so I do need a web server. Could I move them to another 'app service/web app' and those files could be hosted from there? I want to reduce as much load from my VM which does not need to scale but the app service will definitely scale. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I think VM will be the best way to go as it has better resources and can scale when needed. You could run the code in a "web app" which is a less powerful version of your VM but as long as you have to have a web server to serve up the HTML files to the end user your stuck. Neither Blob services or S3 have web servers so they will only allow users to download a file not have it rendered in a browser.

Comment: Thank you Matthew.

Comment: Just for clarification (since this is an accepted answer): Azure Storage objects have URIs, both public and private, and the private URIs may be made public via shared access signature. At that point, you may absolutely provide a URI to an object in blob storage which gets rendered in the browser, even without a web server present. In fact, you could have an entire web site using nothing but blob storage (aside from the fact there's no "default" target - you'd need explicit URIs for, say, `default.html`).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Interesting, when I was testing BLOB out I could never get that to work seems like it works now. I will update answer to reflect this.